# assigning a value to a list within a list

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am having a problem trying to assing a single value to a list within a list

example:

create a list with 11 lists of 11 strings
board=[['.']*(10+1)]*(10+1)

> > > board
> > >       [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

assign value 'O' to the first string of the first list

> > > board[0][0]='O'

I am getting to following output

> > > board
> > >       [['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

Instead I was expected to have this other output that i am not getting:

[['O', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

That's it. I expected to get string 'O' only for the first element of the first listv in board!

I don't understand why i am getting value 'O' to the first value in every single list when I only selected the first one.

Thank you for any comment to all!

Comment: Any code you wrote,?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Yes that's my problem! thank you guys!

Comment: I've added an answer below that clarifies the difference between using a loop vs multiplication to create the rows.

Comment: @RodriguezDavid Feel free to accept (checkmark) and/or upvote an answer below if they've solved your question.

Comment: I think i have just done it! :)

Comment: @RodriguezDavid Yep!  You can also upvote multiple answers (as many as you like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, this line:

```
>>> board = [['.']*(10+1)]*(10+1)
```

appears to create a 2D grid with independent rows of cells however it doesn't quite do that, and this is a common issue experienced with creating n-dimensional lists in Python.

What this code does is create *one* row and then the board is a list where each item in the list references the same row.

You can see that by using `id()`:

```
>>> id(board[0])
4497981128

>>> id(board[1])
4497981128

>>> id(board[2])
4497981128

>>> id(board[0]) == id(board[1]) == id(board[2])
True
```

All three memory addresses are the same, so changing an element at index i in one, changes it in all of them.

What you want to do is generate each row separately:

```
>>> board = [['.']*(10+1) for _ in range(10+1)]
```

(The `_` is a convention for a needed but unused variable.)

This way each row is a separate object in memory:

```
>>> id(board[0]) == id(board[1]) == id(board[2])
False

>>> id(board[0])
4497941384

>>> id(board[1])
4497989256

>>> id(board[2])
4497919688
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your example and your help

Comment: @RodriguezDavid No problem.  If the answer helped you and you feel like it solves your question you can vote on it and click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: How can i do that?:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
board = [["." for i in range(11)] for b in range(11)]

board[0][0] = "O"
```

That will give you the single "O" at the 0th index of the first list.

Comment: with your code the assignment work fine!! Why do you think mine is not working?